# Generate next combination of size k from integer vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics

Lets say I have a vector of integers `v = {0, 1,..., N-1}` of size `N`.

Given a size `k`, I want to generate all `k`-sized combinations of `v`.

```
for example: k = 2, N = 10
    {0,1}, {0,2}, ..., {0,9}, {1,2}, ..., {8,9}
```

But I want to do it one by one, using a method called `NextCombination`:

```
bool NextCombination(vector<int>& v, int k, int N){
    if( is not the last combination){
        turn v into it's next combination
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

that means, given the current state of `v`, the size `k` of the combination and the total number of elements, I'd like to change `v` (if possible) and return a `bool` indicating it was possible to get some next combination out of `v`.

I could not figure out how to make this without some boring recursions, and since this is just small problem of something I'm doing, I would like to figure out some smart/small solution to that.

Comment: What do you mean by getting some next combination out of v?

Comment: I mean if k = 2 and N = 4, i start with vector {0,1} and nextCombination will turn it into {0,2}, then into {0,3}, then {1,2}, then {1,3}, then {2,3} and lastly it returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MBo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39844564/2466618) involving [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) is better as far as readability is concerned.

However, that requires making an N-sized vector of 1s and 0s that you can do without if you really want to save on memory.
The following solution essentially does the same thing in-place.

```
bool NextCombination(vector<int>& v, int k, int N) {
  // We want to find the index of the least significant element
  // in v that can be increased.  Let's call that index 'pivot'.
  int pivot = k - 1;
  while (pivot >= 0 && v[pivot] == N - k + pivot)
    --pivot;

  // pivot will be -1 iff v == {N - k, N - k + 1, ..., N - 1},
  // in which case, there is no next combination.
  if (pivot == -1)
    return false;

  ++v[pivot];
  for (int i = pivot + 1; i < k; ++i)
    v[i] = v[pivot] + i - pivot;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: as i said, this is just a small problem (inside another bigger deal) and the readability of it doesn't matter as soon as it works well.
this did the job, thanks!

Comment: This is the simplest, yet most efficient solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged C++, so the simplest approach for you - make vector length N, containing K ones and (N-K) zeros like `{1,1,0,0,0}` and apply [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/).

At every step positions of ones show - what numbers should be taken for combination.

For example, permutation `{0,1,0,1,0}` corresponds to `(1,3)` combination.

**Edit**

Code from Jörg Arndt's [Matters Computational book](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/) using ready-to-use K-length array (bad formatting and readability)

```
 void first()
 {
     for (ulong k=0; k<k_; ++k)  x_[k] = k;
 }

 ulong next()
 // Return smallest position that changed, return k with last combination
 {
     if ( x_[0] == n_ - k_ )  // current combination is the last
     { first();  return k_; }

     ulong j = k_ - 1;
     // easy case:  highest element != highest possible value:
     if ( x_[j] < (n_-1) )  { ++x_[j];  return j; }

     // find highest falling edge:
     while ( 1 == (x_[j] - x_[j-1]) )  { --j; }

     // move lowest element of highest block up:
     ulong ret = j - 1;
     ulong z = ++x_[j-1];

     // ... and attach rest of block:
     while ( j < k_ )  { x_[j] = ++z;  ++j; }

     return  ret;
 }
```

Comment: isn't there any way with the real values in K-sized vector (instead of N-sized binary vector) ? this way will turn my application slower by having to look more objects than necessary (for example, find 3 objects where N = 100 would not be good)